# When is OP_RETURN cheaper than OP_FALSE OP_IF?

Tags: op-return, transaction-weight, ordinals

Since January 2023 there have been many transactions that embed arbitrary data in the leaf script of a P2TR input using the opcodes OP_FALSE OP_IF (also called "inscription envelope"). This is usually cheaper than using OP_RETURN because the data benefits from the witness discount, but also comes with the overhead of having to first create the P2TR output and then spending it in a subsequent transaction. So, when is it cheaper to use OP_RETURN?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**TL;DR**: OP_RETURN is cheaper for data smaller than 143 bytes.

[image: graph that compares OP_RETURN with inscriptions]

The overhead of an OP_RETURN output is at least 11 bytes:

- amount (8 bytes)
- compact size of script (at least 1 byte)
- script:

  - OP_RETURN opcode (1 byte)
  - push opcode (at least 1 byte)

The overhead of an inscription is at least 118.75 vB (84 base bytes and 139 witness bytes):

- P2TR output (43 bytes)
- P2TR input:

  - outpoint TXID (32 bytes)
  - outpoint index (4 bytes)
  - sequence (4 bytes)
  - compact size of input script (1 byte, script is empty)
  - witness data:

    - compact size of witness stack (1 WU)
    - compact size of signature (1 WU)
    - signature (64 WU)
    - compact size of script (at least 1 WU)
    - script:

      - public key push opcode (1 WU)
      - public key (32 WU)
      - OP_CHECKSIG opcode (1 WU)
      - OP_FALSE opcode (1 WU)
      - OP_IF opcode (1 WU)
      - push opcodes (at least 1 WU)
      - OP_ENDIF opcode (1 WU)
    - compact size of control block (1 WU)
    - control block (33 WU)

The witness discount cancels out the larger overhead at 143 bytes of data, which takes 155 vB using an OP_RETURN and 154.75 vB using an inscription. For anything smaller than that OP_RETURN is cheaper.

Notes:

- The above assumes a best-case scenario in which the P2TR input is included in a transaction that serves some other purpose and would be made anyway. This often isn't the case, in which case the overhead is at least 129.25 vB and OP_RETURN is cheaper for up to at least 158 bytes of data.
- It's necessary to split the data into chunks of 520 bytes in an inscription but not in an OP_RETURN output. This only affects data large enough that it doesn't change the answer.
- We're ignoring the 80-byte standardness limit for OP_RETURN here.